# Why does the position of equation numbers depend on label length?

Tags: cleveref, amsart, amsbook

The `cleveref` package allows users to specify label types using the command `\crefname`. Unfortunately, using these label types with the `amsart` or `amsbook` classes causes the position of the equation number to depend on the label length. How can I make equation number positioning independent of label length?

Concretely, if you consider the following MWE, then second equation number is to the left of the first, and the third is far to the left of the second. All equation numbers should be aligned under the first equation number.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{foo}{bar}{baz}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
  \label{eq:a-really-long-label-but-equation-number-is-well-placed}
  \mathsf{blah blah blah blah blooh blooh blooh blooh} \to \mathsf{blah blah blah blah blah beep boop}
\end{gather}

\begin{gather}
  \label[foo]{eq:short-okish}
  \mathsf{blah blah blah blah blooh blooh blooh blooh} \to \mathsf{blah blah blah blah blah beep boop}
\end{gather}

\begin{gather}
  \label[foo]{eq:long-so-out-in-margin}
  \mathsf{blah blah blah blah blooh blooh blooh blooh} \to \mathsf{blah blah blah blah blah beep boop}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems a bug in `cleveref`.

Comment: amsmath measures the equation, and it sets \label to gobble for this, but with the optional argument this doesn't work, it leaves the label text in the stream.

Comment: The issue doesn’t seem to arise if the `article` document class is in use and the `amsmath` package is loaded by hand.

Comment: @Mico you get it there too, by default you see only overfull boxes, but if you use leqno the labels are misplaced too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Thanks. I hadn't considered the `leqno` option (which is employed by the `amsart` document class by default).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a problem with `cleveref` that doesn't correctly patch `\gmeasure@` and does

```
\let\label\@gobble
```

instead of using some macro that also gobbles an optional argument.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\crefname{foo}{bar}{baz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@gobbleoptone}[2][]{}
\xpatchcmd{\gmeasure@}{\let\label\@gobble}{\let\label\@gobbleoptone}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  \mathsf{blah blah blah blah blooh blooh blooh blooh} \to \mathsf{blah blah blah blah blah beep boop}
  \label{eq:a-really-long-label-but-equation-number-is-well-placed}
\end{gather}

\begin{gather}
  \mathsf{blah blah blah blah blooh blooh blooh blooh} \to \mathsf{blah blah blah blah blah beep boop}
  \label[foo]{eq:short-okish}
\end{gather}

\begin{equation}
  \mathsf{blah blah blah blah blooh blooh blooh blooh} \to \mathsf{blah blah blah blah blah beep boop}
  \label[foo]{eq:long-so-out-in-margin}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]